# How google compute engine or container engine tracks clock sync or not in vm's?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

Few observations:

1. Unable to change time in Cos(Container engine).Is it possible to modify date ?
2. If I changed time in compute engine it didn't get synced after one hour also (Ubuntu image). But I can see ntpd is running. Why it is used?

Answer (score 0):

In google container engine a service timesyncd will be running by default. 
which sync the time with google NTP servers.

If any one needs to change time than stop this service and then change the time/date.

Thanks